# What is the ideal code to text ratio?

Tags: code

is there a formula you have to keep in mind and how much does it affect SERPs? Also is there an efficient way calculating that ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none and any attempt to figure that out is fruitless and outrageous and only points to an attempt to trick search engines. You will be found out or your site will be low quality all around.